# How AlarmManager work with Doze mode in case 9 minutes?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-doze

Below information is from Developer Android side

> Note: Neither setAndAllowWhileIdle() nor setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()
> can fire alarms more than once per 9 minutes, per app.

I want to be more clear for this case.

**Example case:**

I use AlarmManager with method `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` to set two alarms, first Alarm is **7:30** and second Alarm is **7:35**. (device is in Doze mode at this time)

As you can see, the time delta is 5 minutes, less than 9. So second alarm will waiting 9 minutes in order to be fire off at **7:39** or it can't fire any more?

For a reminder app, should I check and alert user if there are two alarm which time different is less than 9 minutes and ask them set another time?

By the way, is setAlarmClock() always work for this case?

Thank you for your advice.